# haml and Getting Started with Rails RailsGuides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, render, partial

Can't figure out why my tags aren't showing in the form that is used in the New and Edit views. I only can see the %h2 Tags. The partial declared after is not generated at all.

Here's what I have. What am I missing? (_form.html.haml)

```
=form_for @post do |form|
.
.
.
%p
  =form.label :content
  %br
  =form.text_area :content

%h2
  Tags
= render :partial => 'tags/form', :locals => {:form => form}

%p
  =form.submit
```

Form located in app/views/tags
_form.html.haml.
None of this shows up:

```
= form.fields_for :tags do |tag_form|
  .field
    = tag_form.label :name, 'Tag:'
    = tag_form.text_field :name
  - unless tag_form.object.nil? || tag_form.object.new_record?
    .field
      = tag_form.label :_destroy, 'Remove:'
      = tag_form.check_box :_destroy
```

Or if it's not here. Where else should I look?

Thanks!

Comment: when you say "app/views/tags _form.html.haml" you do mean "app/views/tags/_form.html.haml" right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of Rails you are using, you many need to change:

```
= form.fields_for :tags do |tag_form|
```

to

```
- form.fields_for :tags do |tag_form|
```

Answer (score 0):

or maybe you should indent

**= render :partial => 'tags/form', :locals => {:form => form}**

two more spaces to the right so that it is inside the form